# stepping forward with LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to forecast a time series and am looking for some guidance on how to predict 2021 - 2025 with this LSTM

I am wondering if there is a simple line I am missing to stretch the predictions past the data set. I really only need y forecasted but I realize I may need to forecast additional features to predict future y, and that is where I am kind of stumped.

```
df_train = df.iloc[0:32]
df_test = df.iloc[32:]

df = df.values
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(df)

#divide the data into train and test data
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.80)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]

#index the data into dependent and independent variables
train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)

#convert data into suitable dimension for using it as input in LSTM network
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)



model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(120, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=120, batch_size=64, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)

plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

#prediction on training and testing data
train_predict = model.predict(train_X)    
test_predict = model.predict(test_X)       

#converting from three dimension to two dimension
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], train_X.shape[2]))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], test_X.shape[2]))

inv_train_predict = concatenate((train_predict, train_X), axis=1)
inv_test_predict = concatenate((test_predict, test_X), axis=1)

#transforming to original scale
inv_train_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_train_predict)
inv_test_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_test_predict)

#predicted values on training data
inv_train_predict = inv_train_predict[:,0]
inv_train_predict

#predicted values on testing data
inv_test_predict = inv_test_predict[:,0]
inv_test_predict 

#scaling back the original train labels
train_y = train_y.reshape((len(train_y), 1))
inv_train_y = concatenate((train_y, train_X), axis=1)
inv_train_y = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_train_y)
inv_train_y = inv_train_y[:,0]

#scaling back the original test labels
test_y = test_y.reshape((len(test_y), 1))
inv_test_y = concatenate((test_y, test_X), axis=1)
inv_test_y = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_test_y)
inv_test_y = inv_test_y[:,0]

#calculating rmse on train data
rmse_train = sqrt(mean_squared_error(inv_train_y, inv_train_predict))
print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse_train)

#calculating rmse on test data
rmse_test = sqrt(mean_squared_error(inv_test_y, inv_test_predict))
print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse_test)

#plotting the graph of test actual vs predicted
inv_test_y = inv_test_y.reshape(-1,1)
inv_test_y.shape

t = np.arange(0,8,1)

plt.plot(t,inv_test_y,label="actual")
plt.plot(t,inv_test_predict,'r',label="predicted")
plt.show()


#plotting the graph to show multi step prediction
plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
plt.plot(df_train.index, inv_train_predict,label="actual")
plt.plot(df_test.index, inv_test_predict, color='r',label="predicted")
plt.legend(loc='best', fontsize='xx-large')
plt.xticks(fontsize=18)
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Right now it plots the predicted values for y which appear to be in line with what I'm looking for but I don't know how to make it step beyond my data set.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

One way of accomplishing that would be to generate time-lagged version(s) of Y corresponding to some time `t - n`, where `n` is the number of time intervals to lag Y for. In this case, the prediction/regression would be done "n time steps ahead".

A simple example. Let us consider the following dataset.

```
X       Y
_____   _____
1       1
2       4
3       9
4       16
5       25
6       36
7       49
8       64
9       81
10      100
```

After generating the time-lagged version with `n = 3`, we obtain the following:

```
X       Y
_____   _____
1       16
2       25
3       36
4       49
5       64
6       81
7       100
```

This approach is not limited to one time-lag, one could generate as many as needed. A way of determining which time-lags to generate would be to doing a correlation analysis between X and different time-lags of Y. Then, from the pool of correlation values, choose the generated time-lagged sequences within the desired threshold. Finally, this approach comes with a price, `max(n1, n2, ..., nN-1, nN)` values are lost from the dataset.